# Optimize MySQL query used to find matches between two tables

Tags: mysql, performance, join, match

On a project I'm working on, I have two tables:

1. `consumption`: Contains historical orders from customers with fields specifying the features of the product they have bought (one product per row)
2. `product`: Contains current product stock

The database engine is InnoDB.

Goals:

- The application must show matches from both sides, I mean:
- When I list current products stock, I want to show a column that displays how many historical orders match with a particular product
- When I list the historical orders, I want to see how many products match with a particular historical order

Database structure for `consumption` and `product` tables plus other related tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `consumption` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_by_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `client_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `data_import_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tmp_consumption_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `material_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `quality_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `thick` DECIMAL(10,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `thick_max` DECIMAL(10,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `width` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `width_max` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `long` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `long_max` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `purchase_price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sale_price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comments` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `annual_consumption` DECIMAL(10,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` ENUM('consumption','request') NULL DEFAULT 'consumption',
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `covering_grammage` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `asp_sup_acab` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `fk_consumption_client1` (`client_id`),
    INDEX `created_by_id` (`created_by_id`),
    INDEX `material_id` (`material_id`),
    INDEX `quality_id` (`quality_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `consumption_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `material` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `consumption_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`quality_id`) REFERENCES `quality` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_consumption_client1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=30673
;

CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `warehouse_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_by_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data_import_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tmp_product_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `code` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `material_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `quality_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `covering_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `finish_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `source` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `thickness` DECIMAL(10,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `width` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tons` DECIMAL(10,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `re` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rm` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `a_percent` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comments` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `warehouse_id` (`warehouse_id`),
    INDEX `material_id` (`material_id`),
    INDEX `quality_id` (`quality_id`),
    INDEX `covering_id` (`covering_id`),
    INDEX `finish_id` (`finish_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `material` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`quality_id`) REFERENCES `quality` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`covering_id`) REFERENCES `covering` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`finish_id`) REFERENCES `finish` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`warehouse_id`) REFERENCES `warehouse` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=740
;
CREATE TABLE `client` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `zone_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `zone2_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `code` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `business_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fiscal_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nif` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `contact_short_name` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `contact_full_name` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `group` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `code_UNIQUE` (`code`),
    INDEX `zone_id` (`zone_id`),
    INDEX `zone2_id` (`zone2_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `client_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `zone` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=443
;
CREATE TABLE `client_group` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `code` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `code` (`code`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=49
;
CREATE TABLE `client_has_group` (
    `client_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `client_id` (`client_id`),
    INDEX `group_id` (`group_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `client_has_group_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `client_has_group_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `client_group` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `covering` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `code` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `group` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `equivalence` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `code_UNIQUE` (`code`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=55
;
CREATE TABLE `finish` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `code` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `group` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `equivalence` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `code_UNIQUE` (`code`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=42
;
CREATE TABLE `material` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `code` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `group` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `equivalence` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `code_UNIQUE` (`code`),
    INDEX `group` (`group`),
    INDEX `equivalence` (`equivalence`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=46
;
CREATE TABLE `quality` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `code` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `group` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `equivalence` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `code_UNIQUE` (`code`),
    INDEX `group` (`group`),
    INDEX `equivalence` (`equivalence`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=980
;
CREATE TABLE `user_filter` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `filter_type` ENUM('consumption','product') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'consumption',
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `is_default` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `client_status` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `client_group` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `material` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `quality` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `thickness` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `width` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tons` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `covering` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `finish` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `re` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rm` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `a_percent` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comments` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `warehouse` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` ENUM('consumption','request') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `fk_user_filter_user1` (`user_id`),
    INDEX `filter_type` (`filter_type`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_user_filter_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;
CREATE TABLE `warehouse` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `zone_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `zone2_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `zone_id` (`zone_id`),
    INDEX `zone2_id` (`zone2_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `warehouse_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `zone` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=37
;
CREATE TABLE `zone` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `zone2_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `zone2_id` (`zone2_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=49
;
```

What I have done to be able to find matches between the two tables:

I have created a LEFT JOIN query between `consumption` and `product` table (that is also joining with additional tables if required).

Looks something like this:

```
SELECT cons.`id` as `consumption_id`, cons.`client_id` as `consumption_client_id`, cons.`material_id` as `consumption_material_id`, cons.`quality_id` as `consumption_quality_id`, cons.`thick` as `consumption_thick`, cons.`thick_max` as `consumption_thick_max`, cons.`width` as `consumption_width`, cons.`width_max` as `consumption_width_max`, cons.`long` as `consumption_long`, cons.`long_max` as `consumption_long_max`, cons.`type` as `consumption_type`, cons.`date_add` as `consumption_date_add`, prod.`id` as `product_id`, prod.`warehouse_id` as `product_warehouse_id`, prod.`code` as `product_code`, prod.`material_id` as `product_material_id`, prod.`quality_id` as `product_quality_id`, prod.`covering_id` as `product_covering_id`, prod.`finish_id` as `product_finish_id`, prod.`thickness` as `product_thickness`, prod.`width` as `product_width`, prod.`tons` as `product_tons` 
      FROM consumption cons 
        INNER JOIN client cli
          ON cli.id=cons.client_id
        LEFT JOIN client_has_group cli_gr
          ON cli_gr.client_id=cons.client_id
        LEFT JOIN product prod
          ON 

          (
            (cons.material_id=prod.material_id)
              OR 
            prod.material_id IN (
              SELECT id FROM material WHERE `equivalence`=(
                  SELECT `equivalence` FROM material WHERE id=cons.material_id
                )
                AND `group`=(
                  SELECT `group` FROM material WHERE id=cons.material_id
                )
            )
          )


 AND 

          (
            (cons.quality_id=prod.quality_id)
              OR 
            prod.quality_id IN (
              SELECT id FROM quality WHERE `equivalence`=(
                  SELECT `equivalence` FROM quality WHERE id=cons.quality_id
                )
                AND `group`=(
                  SELECT `group` FROM quality WHERE id=cons.quality_id
                )
            )
          )


 AND (prod.thickness  >= (cons.thick - 0.1) AND prod.thickness <= (cons.thick_max + 0.1))
 AND (prod.width  >= (cons.width - 1000) AND prod.width <= (cons.width_max + 1000)) 

             WHERE 1 > 0 AND prod.deleted=0 AND cli.status=1 AND cons.date_add >= '2017-10-08 00:00:00' 
        GROUP BY cons.id, prod.id
```

When I want to list products and show matches of consumptions per every product, I have a main query that simply lists the products, then I join that query with the previous query from above and count the matches grouping by product id.

```
SELECT t.*,
       count(f.consumption_id) AS matchesCount
FROM `product` t
LEFT JOIN (...previous query here...) f ON f.product_id=t.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Other notes/considerations:

- The application uses a couple of fields that have the same name in both tables, in order to find matches using `ON` in the `JOIN`
- The application also uses more complex business logic, for example, product material can be equal or can be inside of an equivalence table or group
- The user can save personal filters, that why it is used the `user_filter` table, so as a user I can have multiple "searches" saved and quickly switch from one to the other
- The matches have to be displayed LIVE, I mean, calculated on the fly, not by any cronjob because user filter will always change
- The amount of data the application will be working with right now will be about 35k rows in consumption table and about 1.5k rows in the product table
- The server where the application is hosted is a dedicated server (64GB RAM) running MySQL

I had good performance with 3k rows of consumptions and 100 products, now with 10k+ consumption and 600 products, starting to get gateway timeout from nginx. Guess queries take too long.

I already know that if the `ON` cause has a lot of conditions it will work faster because the results sets are smaller, but if the condition is very wide, it will give a timeout, I guess the resulting rows are too many. Maybe the join will produce millions of rows.

What I'd like to ask is:

- Am I on the right path in order to do "live matches" of data between both tables? is using the JOIN a good solution? I cannot think of another way to do it.
- Apart from trying to optimize queries and indexes, are there any server tweaking I could do to take full advantage of server hardware?
- Any other tips or techniques from someone who has done something similar in another project?

### Update 1: Adding here full query for listing products with consumption matches:

```
SELECT t.*,
       count(f.consumption_id) AS matchesCount
FROM `product` t
LEFT JOIN (


SELECT cons.`id` as `consumption_id`, cons.`client_id` as `consumption_client_id`, cons.`material_id` as `consumption_material_id`, cons.`quality_id` as `consumption_quality_id`, cons.`thick` as `consumption_thick`, cons.`thick_max` as `consumption_thick_max`, cons.`width` as `consumption_width`, cons.`width_max` as `consumption_width_max`, cons.`long` as `consumption_long`, cons.`long_max` as `consumption_long_max`, cons.`type` as `consumption_type`, cons.`date_add` as `consumption_date_add`, prod.`id` as `product_id`, prod.`warehouse_id` as `product_warehouse_id`, prod.`code` as `product_code`, prod.`material_id` as `product_material_id`, prod.`quality_id` as `product_quality_id`, prod.`covering_id` as `product_covering_id`, prod.`finish_id` as `product_finish_id`, prod.`thickness` as `product_thickness`, prod.`width` as `product_width`, prod.`tons` as `product_tons` 
      FROM consumption cons 
        INNER JOIN client cli
          ON cli.id=cons.client_id
        LEFT JOIN client_has_group cli_gr
          ON cli_gr.client_id=cons.client_id
        LEFT JOIN product prod
          ON 

          (
            (cons.material_id=prod.material_id)
              OR 
            prod.material_id IN (
              SELECT id FROM material WHERE `equivalence`=(
                  SELECT `equivalence` FROM material WHERE id=cons.material_id
                )
                AND `group`=(
                  SELECT `group` FROM material WHERE id=cons.material_id
                )
            )
          )



             WHERE 1 > 0 AND prod.deleted=0 AND cli.status=1 AND cons.date_add >= '2017-10-08 00:00:00' 
        GROUP BY cons.id, prod.id


) f ON f.product_id=t.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Query time: 00:02:41 (+ 0,078 sec. network).

Note: The subquery JOIN run separately produces 600k rows. I'm thinking to try to group it somehow in order to make it smaller.

### Update 2: Major improvement achieved by making the count inside the subquery and so reducing the result set used for the JOIN

Basically the subquery instead of returning 600k+ rows, it only returns as much rows as products or consumptions, depending what you're looking for. For that, the matchesCount has been moved inside the subquery instead of outside, and the group by has been changed, depending what list you want to display.

This is how the final queries look like right now:

List consumption and count products that match each consumption:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `t`.*, 
          IFNULL(f.matchesCount, 0) AS matchesCount
   FROM `consumption` `t`
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT cons.`id` AS `consumption_id`,
             cons.`client_id` AS `consumption_client_id`,
             cons.`material_id` AS `consumption_material_id`,
             cons.`quality_id` AS `consumption_quality_id`,
             cons.`thick` AS `consumption_thick`,
             cons.`thick_max` AS `consumption_thick_max`,
             cons.`width` AS `consumption_width`,
             cons.`width_max` AS `consumption_width_max`,
             cons.`long` AS `consumption_long`,
             cons.`long_max` AS `consumption_long_max`,
             cons.`type` AS `consumption_type`,
             cons.`date_add` AS `consumption_date_add`,
             prod.`id` AS `product_id`,
             prod.`warehouse_id` AS `product_warehouse_id`,
             prod.`code` AS `product_code`,
             prod.`material_id` AS `product_material_id`,
             prod.`quality_id` AS `product_quality_id`,
             prod.`covering_id` AS `product_covering_id`,
             prod.`finish_id` AS `product_finish_id`,
             prod.`thickness` AS `product_thickness`,
             prod.`width` AS `product_width`,
             prod.`tons` AS `product_tons`,
             count(prod.`id`) AS matchesCount
      FROM consumption cons
      INNER JOIN client cli ON cli.id=cons.client_id
      LEFT JOIN product prod ON ((cons.material_id=prod.material_id)
                                 OR prod.material_id IN
                                   (SELECT id
                                    FROM material
                                    WHERE `equivalence`=
                                        (SELECT `equivalence`
                                         FROM material
                                         WHERE id=cons.material_id )
                                      AND `group`=
                                        (SELECT `group`
                                         FROM material
                                         WHERE id=cons.material_id ) ))
      AND ((cons.quality_id=prod.quality_id)
           OR prod.quality_id IN
             (SELECT id
              FROM quality
              WHERE `equivalence`=
                  (SELECT `equivalence`
                   FROM quality
                   WHERE id=cons.quality_id )
                AND `group`=
                  (SELECT `group`
                   FROM quality
                   WHERE id=cons.quality_id ) ))
      AND (prod.thickness >= (cons.thick - 0.1)
           AND prod.thickness <= (cons.thick_max + 0.1))
      AND (prod.width >= (cons.width - 1000)
           AND prod.width <= (cons.width_max + 1000))
      WHERE 1 > 0
        AND prod.deleted=0
        AND cli.status=1
        AND cons.date_add >= '2017-10-08 00:00:00'
      GROUP BY cons.id) f ON f.consumption_id=t.id

   GROUP BY t.id
```

List products and count consumptions that match each product:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t.*,
          IFNULL(f.matchesCount, 0) AS matchesCount
   FROM `product` `t`
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT cons.`id` AS `consumption_id`,
             cons.`client_id` AS `consumption_client_id`,
             cons.`material_id` AS `consumption_material_id`,
             cons.`quality_id` AS `consumption_quality_id`,
             cons.`thick` AS `consumption_thick`,
             cons.`thick_max` AS `consumption_thick_max`,
             cons.`width` AS `consumption_width`,
             cons.`width_max` AS `consumption_width_max`,
             cons.`long` AS `consumption_long`,
             cons.`long_max` AS `consumption_long_max`,
             cons.`type` AS `consumption_type`,
             cons.`date_add` AS `consumption_date_add`,
             prod.`id` AS `product_id`,
             prod.`warehouse_id` AS `product_warehouse_id`,
             prod.`code` AS `product_code`,
             prod.`material_id` AS `product_material_id`,
             prod.`quality_id` AS `product_quality_id`,
             prod.`covering_id` AS `product_covering_id`,
             prod.`finish_id` AS `product_finish_id`,
             prod.`thickness` AS `product_thickness`,
             prod.`width` AS `product_width`,
             prod.`tons` AS `product_tons`,
             count(cons.`id`) AS matchesCount
      FROM consumption cons
      INNER JOIN client cli ON cli.id=cons.client_id
      LEFT JOIN product prod ON cons.material_id=prod.material_id
      AND cons.quality_id=prod.quality_id
      WHERE 1 > 0
        AND prod.deleted=0
        AND cli.status=1
      GROUP BY prod.id) f ON f.product_id=t.id
   WHERE deleted=0
   GROUP BY t.id
```

Both queries take less than 1 second to execute (each).

Note: I still use the previous queries in my application, for example, when I want a break down of the list of products that match a single consumption, or the other way around. In that case I already add a filter per consumption id or product id that reduces the size of the result set a lot.

Comment: You have consumption of products which don't exist in your products table? I'd start by fixing the data.

Answer (score 1):

If `client_has_group` is "many:1", that is the wrong way to do it.  You don't need the extra table.

`INT` is always 4 bytes.  Consider smaller datatypes.  Eventually the size of the database may add to your problems.

Do you *really* need `date_add` and `date_upd`.  They seem like clutter that you will never use.

Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )` where practical.  Switch to `JOIN` or `EXISTS`.

Why so many tables with code + group + equivalence?  Could they be a single group?  Do you need all 3 columns?  Do you need `id` since `code` is `UNIQUE`?  There comes a point where a schema is "over-normalized" and performance suffers without helping space much.

`OR` is a performance killer in some contexts.

"Correlated subqueries" are useful in some situations, but this one is probably better done via a `JOIN`:

```
AND `group` = ( SELECT `group` FROM quality WHERE id=cons.quality_id )
```

Beware of aggregates (eg, `COUNT`) with `JOIN`; you may be getting an inflated value.  This is because the `JOIN` happens first.

Answer (score 0):

1. why need
       LEFT JOIN client_has_group cli_gr ON cli_gr.client_id=cons.client_id
           it never used
2. why need GROUP BY cons.id, prod.id  if you select all fields maybe select only what you need
3. try this select, i think it will be more faster

   ```
   SELECT count(*), prod.*    
   FROM consumption cons 
   INNER JOIN client cli ON cli.id=cons.client_id   
   INNER JOIN   material m ON  m.id=cons.material_id    
   INNER JOIN   quality q ON  q.id=cons.quality_id
       LEFT JOIN product prod
       ON    
         (
           (cons.material_id=prod.material_id)
             OR 
           prod.material_id IN (
             SELECT id FROM material WHERE `equivalence`=m.equivalence
               AND `group`=m.group
           )
         )
   AND 
         (
           (cons.quality_id=prod.quality_id)
             OR 
           prod.quality_id IN (
             SELECT id FROM quality WHERE `equivalence`=q.equivalence
               AND `group`=q.group
           )
         )
    AND (prod.thickness  >= (cons.thick - 0.1) AND prod.thickness <= (cons.thick_max + 0.1))
    AND (prod.width  >= (cons.width - 1000) AND prod.width <= (cons.width_max + 1000)) 

    WHERE 1 > 0 AND prod.deleted=0 AND cli.status=1 AND cons.date_add >= '2017-10-08 00:00:00'
   group by  prod.id
   ```
4. maybe better do calculation count in background and add this field in product and consumption table.